# Spring boot - How to Improve api response time for Application with monthly data refresh

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot, caching

We are using spring boot `1.5.10` Release version along with mongodbrepository.

We have huge data so we are loading  static data(select * from table) on server startup using postconstruct.

Api response size is Approx 25MB we are compressing it using gzip so size becomes 5MB.

We have multiple services, every service  includes `@PostConstruct` to load (select * from table)frequently used data to prepare maps to improve performance.

We are preparing map<id, custom Obj> from findall db query in each service
1 service for reference..

@PostCounstruct
Init(){
List list = xyzRepository.findAll();
Map<String, MyObj> map = new HashMap():
for(MyObj Obj : list){
map.put(obj.id, Obj)
}
}

User will get fast response from map when  findById / findAll / findByList(List employees> emps) called

Every month our  db gets refreshed/updated. Once we refreshed db we are restarting spring boot application.

Problem which we are facing if there is any db refresh happened ( due to some issue/delay) within month in database, we need to restart server to get correct data instead of stale data.

We tried `@Cacheable` in every service but 1st db hit taking too much time.( As we are doing select * from table).

We made parallel ajax call to get data.
Application dashboard need to plot data which is approx 30MB (gzip 5mb) which is pain..

Approx 2000 users for application
20 services..
Each service calling  to get data ( some are getting static data from map which is initialised in postcounstruct)

Currently We are restarting server monthly when db refresh happened.

How we can get latest data without server restart when there is unexpected db refresh?

---------[Edit-1]-----

Upvoted answer suggest that populate new/update data in every map present in every service.

1.Application startup time will be high as map will be populated from database.

2.Overhead to populate/maintain data in some time interval(nightly/alternate day/Weekly) in Java maps.

What if more data will increase in each collection/table & every month.

Need expert review on upvoted answer.

---

Thanks for reading question

Comment: A stop-gap solution might be to have a private API to tell the app to re-load it's data, e.g., get all the current keys from the map and fetch the related (updated) data, and update the map (in a thread safe way).  Longer term, determine **why** does it take __too much time__?  Do the queries executed by the app need to be optimized? Does the app know too much about the data structure, resulting in multiple database calls?  Could DB stored procedures/functions be used in place of app code?  Does the database need scaled up?  Is there a network issue?  Red/black deployments?

Comment: @AndrewS I agree with you Andrew, for this kind of problem.
He needs to add more & more information inorder to help with the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can introduce some interface

```
interface Refreshable {
    void refresh();
}
```

All beans which do data caching during post construct should implement it

```
@Component
public class SomeDataProvider implements Refreshable {
   ...

   @Override void refresh() { /*here refresh data*/ }

   @PostConstruct
   public void postConstruct() {
       ...
       refresh();
       ...
   } 
}
```

and now expose rest endpoint which you can call whenever database is changed

```
@RestControler
public class ForceRefresh {

   @Autowired 
   private List<Refreshable> refreshables; // here Spring will inject all services which can be refreshed

   @PostMapping
   public void forceRefresh() {
       // refresh concurrently using common thread pool
       refreshables.stream().parallel().forEach(Refreshable::refresh);
   }

}
```

Alternatively, instead of REST endpoint you can implement nightly reload, see Spring docs for `@ @EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled`.

---

As a side note - using `@PostConstruct` for loading is NOT an optimal approach because Spring loads beans in single-threaded mode. Better to implement `ApplicationReadyEvent` listener, inject a list of `Refreshable`s as in example above and load data asynchronously using thread pool (==utilizing whole power of multiple CPUs on your server and on Mongo).

Comment: Thanks for response. I would like to understand how refreshableS will be  used to refresh () data in forceRefresh() api ? Example plz.

Comment: Yes, I also thought to remove PostConstruct to load data & use ApplicationReadyEvent which will load required static data. I don't find strong recommendation to use ApplicationReadyEvent instead of Postcounstruct.

Comment: " I don't find strong recommendation" - in particular application there could be no difference. But in Docker/Kubernetes/you_name_it world quick start&reply on health checking endpoint could be very important. While Spring is calling post-constructs then application cannot serve requests (including health endpoint). If you do data caching later then application can serve requests while data are being cached.

Comment: " I would like to understand how refreshableS" - added simple implementation

Comment: Clean solution especially if you will do it in separate scheduled task. However since you are in multithreading context, you have to make sure that the data to be cached (which will be logically in your SomeDataProvider) is volatile. So, your processing thread will use the latest version. (This will be safer if you decide to increase the refresh frequency) . Good luck.

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov In services, Do we need to add anything in List<Refreshable> refreshables ?  How spring inject all services refresh in refreshableS ?

Comment: @StackOverFlow, Spring will look to all your Beans which implement the interface Refreshable and inject them in the List<Refreshable>.

Comment: @StackOverFlow it is part of `@Autowired` contract https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: exposing this as api can have catastrophic failure :/

Comment: with proper security it will be fine

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar business problem where we get each month's data to refresh and our deployment in Kubernetes based on so same service multiple pods as spring-boot service.

**My Approach 1:**

1. Maps based in-memory cache objects based on data requests and responses to be generated.
2. Maps generated on the application start event.
3. Spring-based @Scheduled task to check DB for new data availability each night.
4. In the database having a table to provide information if new month data is added so step 3 keeps checking that table periodically if new data then only it initiates the cache rebuilding.
5. Extra checks of sampling of data to prevent the condition where the data population in dB is completed before the cache rebuild starts.
6. Rebuild the cache if till step 5 everything is successful.
7. If data keep getting large need to move the in-memory cache to separate cache servers like Redis or Memcache.

This is will make startup time a bit high but that all depends on data points of request and response. Data points need to be carefully used as per the business need not like cache everything. But it will never force to have a manual startup of the server.

For all cashing queries using the JDBC query approach in place of hibernate approach takes more time/memory whereas the JDBC template made query execution faster.

All caching queries need to be tested for execution plan too so it can tell any missing indexes before moving to production.

**My Approach 2:**

Approach 1 logic but all in separate app.

Another performance way can be taking out caching logic as a separate app and deploy them in their own pods and use Kubernetes scheduler as crontab which will rebuild the cache as defined above and service will call these pods to cater then request/response from the cache. This approach will offload the service memory overhead due to the cache.

Having in-memory caching as a separate app will give the advantage on my first approach is that we can have a cache swap so till the new cache we build service will be catering requests from old cache, the user experience will not have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

I think to solve this kind of problem, you need to build a matrix of your API by any monitoring service because we do not have a full image.

- I suggest you check any monitoring tool (Prometheus or Datadog)
- APM (Application performance motoring) like Dynatrace
  It will help you to check every API request & your SQL queries what is happening to them the response time.
- want to add also redis for caching inorder to make only 1 hiy of a query & if you have any problem happened in database, you could check al messages in the queue.

https://redis.io/topics/client-side-caching

After that, you could check where is the issue exactly from the code of API service or from the database itself.

Comment: Could you plz review #3 answer by Alexander ? Provide your comment if any

Answer (score 0):

Since `MongoDB` doesn't offer any mechanism to call your application back if any event happens, you have alternative solution by creating a `Schedule Tasks` with Spring Boot. The task will update the data cached based on a frequency you define.
You can keep the `postcontruct` method for the first start-up of you application.

Another point, you can improve the performance of your queries by adding indexes. (Maybe, this was done)

Comment: Could you plz review #3 answer by Alexander ? Provide your comment if any

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing the following:

- Annotate response methods with `@Cacheable("#yourKey")`. Also, remember to add `@EnableCaching` to the application.
- Call the cached response method from within the application after it starts to reduce the time consumed for next calls.
- Create a "**refresh**" endpoint/method to be called to refresh the DB and annotate it with `@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, key="#yourKey")`.

Maybe you can even add `@Scheduled` to your refresh endpoint/method to make it run automatically every specified period of time. Also, remember to add `@EnableScheduling` to the application.

For the DB, I think indexing the necessary tables could be helpful if not done already.

Comment: What we frequently do in similar cases is to just have a @Scheduled annotation which replaces the Map reference. The update is performed in a backround (Scheduling) thread. Since there are no synchronize requirements, simply swapping map references is the easiest